# Adding a value to datepicker

Tags: angular, angular-material

I get a timestamp from the server and would like to set the date as the value of my input field. My server returns the correct value but my input field stays empty and there are no errors.

```js
private profileFormGroup = this.fb.group({
  dateOfBirth: ['', MAT_DATEPICKER_VALIDATORS]
});

ngOnInit() {
  this.profileService.getEntities().subscribe(data => {
    console.log(data.dateOfBirth); // retruns the timestamp 771544800
    this.profileFormGroup.get('dateOfBirth').patchValue(data.dateOfBirth);
  });
}
```

```html
<mat-form-field>
  <label><input #dateOfBirth matInput (blur)="_update('personal', 'dateOfBirth', dateOfBirth.value)" (click)="picker.open()" [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a date" formControlName="dateOfBirth" autocomplete="off" [max]="maxDate" [min]="minDate"></label>
  <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker touchUi #picker startView="multi-year"></mat-datepicker>
  <mat-error *ngIf="profileFormGroup.get('dateOfBirth').errors">Date is not valid</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

Why does my input field keeps being empty?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone has the same problem:

You need to format the date to make it look like YYYY-MM-DD.

In my case, I did it that way:

```js
  private static _formatDate(timestamp: number): string {
    const date = new Date(timestamp * 1000); // * 1000, because it's a unix timestamp
    return date.toISOString().substring(0, 10);
  }

  ngOnInit() {
      console.log(ProfileComponent._formatDate(data.dateOfBirth));
    });
  }
```